# Why I could not find the rbac option in Yii Interactive Tool v1.1 (based on Yii v1.1.5)

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii Interactive Tool v1.1 (based on Yii v1.1.5) to create my RBAC authorization hierarchy. But after I enter the “>> help rbac” I can only saw：

```
>> help rbac

 - controller
 - crud
 - form
 - help
 - model
 - module
```

I could not find the rbac option. Could you tell me why？

Answer (score 0):

When I used the yii shell tool， my command must include the path of "index.php".

for example:

E:\projects\yiiroot\trackstar\protected>yiic shell ../index.php

E:\projects\yiiroot\trackstar\protected>yiic shell config/main.php ../index.php

If I only input the "E:\projects\yiiroot\trackstar\protected>yiic shell".

It will return an error such as "... does not exist or is not an entry script file."